# Magento 1.9.1 how to un-queue a newsletter

Tags: magento, queue, newsletter

I am using Magento CE v 1.9.1.0 and after I add a newsletter to the queue I am wondering if it is possible to delet/remove it from the que. Life for example if I added a template to the que in error and need to remove it from the que. The only solution I seem to be able to do is delete the template and that will remove it from the que. However what If I do not want to delete the template and just want to 'un-queue' the newsletter?? In the screenshot below you can see under actions I only have a 'preview' option. Is there no way to from the admin add the ability to un-queue it?

http://postimg.org/image/6yjkis6u5/

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the corresponding entries in the `newsletter_queue`, `newsletter_queue_link`, `newsletter_queue_store_link` table in your Magento database.

There is no build-in UI for this in magento afaik.